# Having two Spy Objects in one service is not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-services

When I have both the Spy Objects set up like this:

```
  let recipeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('RecipeService',
    ['setRecipes', 'getRecipes', 'getRecipe'],
    {recipesChanged: of(mockRecipes), recipes: mockRecipes}
  );

  let mockShoppingListServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ShoppingListService',
    ['addIngredients']
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        {provide: RecipeService, useValue: recipeSpy},
        {provide: ShoppingListService, useValue: mockShoppingListServiceSpy}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(RecipeService);
  });
```

Only one of the spies work.

These are the functions in the service file:

```
getRecipe(index: number) {
    return this.recipes[index];
}

addIngredientsToShoppingList(ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
    this.slService.addIngredients(ingredients);
}
```

For example if I comment out one of the useValue lines, the other one will work.

```
  it('should get the recipe per the index', () => {
    recipeSpy.getRecipe.and.returnValue(mockRecipes[1]);
    service.getRecipe(1);
    expect(recipeSpy.getRecipe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  });

  it('should add ingredients to the shopping list', () => {
    service.addIngredientsToShoppingList(mockIngredients);
    expect(mockShoppingListServiceSpy.addIngredients).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockIngredients);
  });
```

If I set up the code like this^, I get an error for the 2nd test stating "TypeError: service.addIngredientsToShoppingList is not a function."

The only way to get rid of this error is if I comment out "{provide: RecipeService, useValue: recipeSpy}," but this will cause the first test to fail.

How can I get both these spies to work at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're testing the `RecipeService`. If so, you should be providing the real implementation of the `RecipeService` and not a mock (you mention this in your comments).

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        RecipeService,
        {provide: ShoppingListService, useValue: mockShoppingListServiceSpy}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(RecipeService);
  });
```

The first test is not a good test anyway, we are calling the method explicitly and expecting it to be called.

Check out the test I have written below. I assume the recipe by index 1 exists and I assert that it indeed is recipe of index 1 (Spaghetti).

```
it('should get the recipe per the index', () => {
    // get the recipe by index 1 (assuming it exists)
    const recipe = service.getRecipe(1);
    expect(recipe.name).toBe('Spaghetti');
  })
```

Comment: If I remove "RecipeService" from the providers, I get an error that there is no provider for RecipeService.

Comment: And in the test that you are giving, if I do a console for recipe, I get undefined.

Comment: @Neil: do not remove "RecipeService" from the providers, but provide it as plain "RecipeService" instead of "{provide: RecipeService, useValue: ...}"

Comment: Slim is right and you get undefined because `this.recipes[1]` is undefined. I am not sure how `this.recipes` looks like. Try `0` instead of `1`, make sure `this.recipes` is an array of recipes before testing it.